# Jekyll build not closing when run as Node child process

Tags: node.js, jekyll, gulp, child-process

I'm trying to run `jekyll build` as a node child process in a gulp file. The issue is that `jekyll build` seems to be running multiple times and never closes.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the `jekyll build` process modifies the markdown file which would cause `gulp.watch` to run again. I don't see any evidence of this though.

If I just run `jekyll build` from the terminal I get this:

```
Configuration file: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_config.yml
            Source: /home/user_name/projects/project_name
       Destination: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_site
      Generating... 
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

When I run it as a node child process I get this:

```
[20:59:03] Configuration file: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_config.yml
            Source: /home/user_name/projects/project_name
       Destination: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_site
      Generating... 

[20:59:03] Configuration file: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_config.yml
            Source: /home/user_name/projects/project_name
       Destination: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_site
      Generating... 

[20:59:03] Configuration file: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_config.yml
            Source: /home/user_name/projects/project_name
       Destination: /home/user_name/projects/project_name/_site
      Generating...
```

It keeps repeating like that 20+ times then just stops and doesn't output anything after that.

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var spawn   = require('child_process').spawn;
var gutil   = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch('**/*.md', function (e) {
    var cp      = spawn('jekyll', ['build']),
        stdout  = '',
        stderr  = '';

    cp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

    cp.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      stdout += data;
      gutil.log(data);
    });

    cp.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

    cp.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      stderr += data;
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(data));
    });

    cp.on('error', function (err) {
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('gulp-jekyll', err));
    });

    cp.on('close', function (code) {
      gutil.log('Done with exit code ', code);
      gutil.log('Jekyll has completed the build process.');
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright, it seems the issue was that I forgot to exclude my `node_modules` directory in the jekyll `_config.yml` file. There must have been so many markdown files that it overwhelmed jekyll.

Still, I'm not sure why they even triggered the `gulp.watch` in the first place, as they were not edited.